# Need to subset by excluding multiple values in a categorical variable

Tags: r, subset, categorical-data

I have a categorical field, and I want to subset by 'excluding' multiple values.

Initially, I had assumed I could just list out all the values I want directly into the code, or create a separate list and add it back into the code ( see below).

```
subset(data, data$variable != c("x1", "x2", "x3"))
```

or

```
Exclude_Prod = c("x1", "x2", "x3")

subset(data, data$variable != Exclude_Prod)
```

I have multiple values in a single field, which is a categorical variable.

I want to exclude these multiple values and then subset the data. The reason why I want to exclude is because there are less values compared to the ones I want to keep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: Replace with relevant variables. data3 is the dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
```

Using some fake data:
With `base` R

```
data3[!data3$Exclude_Prod%in%c("x1","x2"),]
```

The "disadvantage" is that base R preserves the original indexing.
With `dplyr`

```
data3<-data.frame(Sales=c(11,12,13),Exclude_Prod = c("x1", "x2", "x3"))
data3 %>% 
  filter(!Exclude_Prod%in%c("x1","x2"))
```

Result:

```
 Sales Exclude_Prod
1    13           x3
```

Original Answer:

```
 mtcars %>% 
      mutate(ID=row.names(.)) %>% 
      select(ID) %>% 
      filter(!ID%in%c("Volvo 142E","Toyota Corona"))#eg Variable%in%c("x1", "x2", "x3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Nelson. After hard searching, getting help, and trial and error I used `tidyverse`:

```
data2 <- data1 %>%
  filter(variable != "x1" & variable != "x2")
```

Answer (score 0):

a `data.table` way:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(data)[! variable %in% c("x1", "x2", "x3"), ]
```

Please notice that naming a data frame "data" is bad idea, as there's a function  called `data` in the `utils` package.